# Nested cross validation vs overall model validation

Tags: python

I would like to use a Decision Tree model on my dataset to predict a binary target variable.

I have cleaned my data and split my data into features and target.

I have then split this data into test and train:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( feature, target, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 100)
```

I have split the train data into train and validate:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_val = train_test_split( feature, target, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 100)
```

I have fit a decision tree model to the train data:

```
clft = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
```

clft.fit(X_train, y_train)

I have used this model to predict the unseen data, the test data.
This produces an accuracy of the model.

```
predictTree=clft.predict(X_test)
print (metrics.accuracy_score(predictTree, y_test))
```

I would then like to use Nested Cross validation to improve this accuracy
and optimise the model:

```
#set parameter grid
parameter_grid = {'max_depth': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
              'max_features': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
#specifiy cross validation
cross_validation = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10)
cross_validation.get_n_splits(X_train, y_train)
#finds optimised parameters
grid_search = GridSearchCV(clft, param_grid = parameter_grid,
                      cv = cross_validation)
#best estimater is fitted for x_train and y_train
grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
#outer loop with cv 5
 scoresclt = model_selection.cross_val_score(grid_search, X_train, y_train, 
 cv=5)
```

I am uncertain of the Nested CV, where to use the validation set, and where to go from here.

To my knowledge, the model should be applied to the test set and the validation set to give proper accuracy for the model.

My Nested Cv, uses grid search as the inner loop, which is placed in the outer loop run by model_selection.cross_val_score. Is this correct?

Should I place my validation set in the Nested CV somewhere? or do I use the model from Nested Cv on the validation set? Do I then calculate this accuracy as the true accuracy for the model?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there. Here's what I'd do:

**Train and Test Split**:

First split the input into `train` and `test`; but I'd also take the domain knowledge into account. Try to have your `test` set as representative of the real world as possible. For instance, if the input are handwritten digits and you know who has written which digits (i.e. writers), choose some "writers" and take everything they've written as the test set. Or if your data comes from different labs or hospitals, take some of those labs and everything they've given as the test set. The way you should split your input as `train` and `test` really depends on the domain. Randomly choosing samples is often not the best option.

**Nested Cross Validation and Parameter Grid**:

Now you can do what you do on the `train` data, i.e. assume your `GridSearchCV` to be your model (`sklearn` gives the same API for it as the usual models, therefore you can pretend it's a normal model, as you've done in your code), and do a cross validation on that model to get a performance estimate. What you'd do next is usually to tune the parameter grid of the grid search, to get a better performance. For instance, in the case of a kernel method, you may include or exclude certain kernels from your search space.

**Final Evaluation**:

Once you're done finding a parameter grid you're comfortable with, you'd then apply that on your whole `train` data, and evaluate the resulting model on the `test` you set aside. If you want your results to be as valid as it can be, never change anything after you see the result of your model on the `test` data. Do your optimizations before you see the results on the `test` set.

Comment: Thank you so much for this reply. This is very helpful and imformative :)